# Sidekiq 7 / Redis-client not working (on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, redisclient

I am using Sidekiq on an app hosted on Heroku.
I have been using the `redis` gem.

Now I am trying to upgrade to sidekiq 7 which uses `redis-client` instead of `redis`. And when doing so I get this error:

`redis-client requires Redis 6+ with HELLO command available`

The Redis instance I have on Heroku is on the version `6.2.6` (so Redis 6+) (picture attached)

Below my `redis.rb` file (which is in initializers). I replaced Redis with RedisClient but I still get the error in both cases (in the case where I use the `redis` gem with Sidekiq 7 and the case where I use `redis-client`).
It means that it is when the Sidekiq inner code is using `redis-client` that the error is happening.

Any thoughts or ideas would be highly appreciated  Thanks in advance!

I was expecting this to work as my Redis instance is on a 6+ version

```
url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
end
```

[image: Screenshot of Redis instance]

Comment: Maybe remove both `redis = Redis.new` The first one has no Url, and for the second one options are not in a hash and not used by Sidekiq anyway. Sidekiq creates their own redis clients. Also you assign these redis connection to a local variable. Usually when using redis manually (assigning redis keys etc.. in your code by yourself you make it a constant so that it is available in your whole app such as `Redis_c = Redis.new({url: url})` but this does not need to be in the Sidekiq initializer). Also check your environment variable `REDISCLOUD_URL` is indeed present on your Heroku project.

Comment: Please add your code as a code block using text

Comment: @Maxence Thanks for your help. 100% the `Redis.new` lines are useless. But they are also harmless, in the sense that removing them doesn't solve the issue, right? :(

The `REDISCLOUD_URL` is there - the app works totally fine with Sidekiq 6.5

Answer (score 2):

Searching the Sidekiq issues for "HELLO" gives you this issue:

https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5594#issuecomment-1302384905

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your redis-server (on your machine) to 6+ version. Don't forget to restart it after upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here in my application.
Although the version 6.2.6 is 6+ The error only stopped when I used Redis on version 6.2.12.
In staging I am using a "Heroku Data for Redis®* Mini" (with Redis 6.2.12) and it is running normally in Sidekiq 7
In production I am using a "Memetria for Redis®* Mini" (Redis 7)

I don't know if it is possible to choose the version of "Heroku Data for Redis®* Mini" I already had this addon installed in stage.